# XSLT Selecting specific sibling nodes between two nodes of xml

Tags: xml, xslt

Suppose I have the following XML structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"?>
<WTT>
<Msg 
    UserText="Iswritable = true" >
</Msg>
<Test 
   BaseLvl="Msg" >
</Test>
<start
   id = "1" >
</start>
<Msg 
   UserText="Iswritable = true" >
</Msg>
<Test 
   BaseLvl="Msg"  >
</Test>
<Msg 
   UserText="WriteBuffers = 2">
</Msg>
<Test 
   BaseLvl="Txt" >
</Test>
<Msg 
   UserText="ReadBuffers = 1">
</Msg>
<end
   id ="1" >
</end>

<start
   id = "2" >
</start>
<Test
   BaseLvl="sound" > 
</Test>
<Test 
   BaseLvl="Msg" >
</Test>
<Msg 
   UserText="vertexbuffers = 1">
</Msg>
<end
   id ="2" >
</end>
<Msg 
   UserText="vertexbuffers = 1">
</Msg>
</WTT>
```

Output :

```
<start
   id = "1" >
</start>
<Msg 
   UserText="Iswritable = true" >
</Msg>
<Msg 
   UserText="ReadBuffers = 1">
</Msg>
<end
   id ="1">
</end>
<start
   id = "2" >
</start>
<Msg 
   UserText="vertexbuffers = 1">
</Msg>
<end
   id ="2" >
</end>
```

The structure of the xml is not fixed and any tag can be put anywhere.
Is there a way to do this?
I tried using foreach and selecting only msg nodes but we cannot break the foreach in xslt.
I just have to select all the `<msg/>` tags between `<start/>` and the `<end/>` tags in separate groups.

Comment: Please post (1) a **well-formed** XML input, (2) the expected output of the transformation, and (3) the version of XSLT you're using.

Comment: I have edited the things that you asked for. I am using xslt version 1.0

Comment: Why is `<Msg UserText="WriteBuffers = 2"/>` not included in your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/WTT">
    <root>
        <xsl:copy-of select="start | end | Msg[preceding-sibling::start[1]/@id = following-sibling::end[1]/@id]"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your XML input, will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <start id="1"/>
   <Msg UserText="Iswritable = true"/>
   <Msg UserText="WriteBuffers = 2"/>
   <Msg UserText="ReadBuffers = 1"/>
   <end id="1"/>
   <start id="2"/>
   <Msg UserText="vertexbuffers = 1"/>
   <end id="2"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But, actually in my xslt I am using a foreach loop.
Suppose now I am at the first `<start/>` node now. So now I use the code

`xslt:value-of select = "following-sibling::Msg[preceding-sibling::Test[1]/@id = following-sibling::Test[1]/@id]/@UserText"></xslt:value-of>` But I am able to fetch only one `<Msg/>` sibling's userText and not all

Comment: @MayurJadhav I don't see why you would need to use `xsl:for-each` in order to produce the output that you yourself have specified.

Comment: This is just a small version of things that I have to do, there is lots of other processing that is also done with other tags. I can't post the exact xml and exact xslt code due to some reasons. But I don't know why`xslt:value-of select = "following-sibling::Msg[preceding-sibling::start[1]/@id = following-sibling::end[1]/@id]/@UserText"></xslt:value-of>` isn't working

Comment: @MayurJadhav If there are other things you need to do, then use `xsl:apply-templates` instead of `xsl:copy-of` and write templates to further process the selected nodes. I will not answer follow-up questions that are not pertinent to my suggestion.